# Implement stripe subscriptions with .net framework 4.7.2 and not .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-framework-version, stripe-payments

I want to implement stripe subscription for a service i am offering on my website. The code on the stripe documentation uses .netcore but my web application is in .net framework and i do not want to change to .net core because my hosting service provider does not support .net core. Is there a way of implementing subscriptions with stripe using .net framework? - How i want this to work is that when a user logs in they can click a subscription page which will allow them to select the service they want and then they input their card details - when they do this they will be charged on the very day this request happen and every month on that day. I have looked at various examples but i cannot get my head around how I would do this in code.

Comment: i got the code examples from the stripe github - https://github.com/stripe-samples/subscription-use-cases/tree/master/usage-based-subscriptions/server/dotnet

Comment: Check out the demo app and download the code to accept payments and subscriptions with all payment methods with Stripe's newest product, Payment Element --> https://techtolia.com/Stripe/New

Answer (score 4):

You could use the Stripe Javascript API with Stripe Checkout. You just have to enable Stripe Checkout in the dashboard:

[https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client#:~:text=1%20Enable%20Checkout%20Dashboard,feel%20of%20your%20checkout%20page](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client#:%7E:text=1%20Enable%20Checkout%20Dashboard,feel%20of%20your%20checkout%20page).

Then when you create a new product (which can be a subscription) and assign a price, you will have the option to create a Checkout code snippet. These snippets are quite generic but aren't too difficult to modify to sure your needs.

#### Edit:

After checking the Stripe.Net nuget page, the latest version is still compatible with .Net Framework 4.6.1, so any code samples you see using .net core are still applicable to .Net Framework 4.6.1+

For example:

```
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "sk_test_51HAxQFH39e4DIylVXXTGZgYZyEBhV0jLZ0AL4oQ1vUt8kTC5nB5sIzx6VcmsG41JbK8SA6JWDb7r3OfsFhO5omdD009OQF1OOQ";

var service = new ProductService();
service.Get("prod_HkaQiWW1JbzNyc");
```

will work in .net core and any .Net Framework 4.6.1+ application or website.

https://stripe.com/docs/api

Comment: this is for one time payments - i want to create for subscriptions you see- will it be similar or does it require new code?

Comment: Checkout does support Subscriptions.  I'd suggest you read the link shared here.

Comment: as @floatingLomas said, you just change the price from one time to recurring and then set the period, monthly for example.

https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-to-create-products-and-prices#:~:text=Creating%20products%20and%20prices%20using,you%20track%20inventory%20or%20provisioning.

I also quickly checked Nuget for Stripe.net and the latest version is for ,Net Standard v2.0, but it is still compatible with .Net Framework v4.6.1, so you can still use it, even if you aren't using .Net Core

Comment: okay thanks i just implemented this - however i need to allow my database to know that this customer has paid so it can show them subscribe content. i was told webhooks was a way to do this - i have created a new question for this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63783919/trying-to-setup-web-hook-for-stripe-using-netframework-asp-mvc-c-sharp