# Trying to setup web hook for stripe using ASP.NET MVC and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webhooks, stripe-payments

I have implemented some front end code which when a user clicks the checkout button they are redirected to a stripe page where they can input their card payment details. the code has a successful URL and failed URL. if the customer enter valid payment details - they are redirected to the successful URL, i need to update my database to ensure that my backend knows that this specific user has paid and can now view subscribed content. I am trying to setup web hooks in order to do this, so I know if the user has paid, cancelled etc.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Stripe;

namespace workspace.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class StripeWebHook : Controller
{
    // You can find your endpoint's secret in your webhook settings
    const string secret = "whsec_...";

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var json = await new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

        try
        {
            var stripeEvent = EventUtility.ConstructEvent(json,
                Request.Headers["Stripe-Signature"], secret);

            // Handle the checkout.session.completed event
            if (stripeEvent.Type == Events.CheckoutSessionCompleted)
            {
                var session = stripeEvent.Data.Object as Checkout.Session;

                // Fulfill the purchase...
                HandleCheckoutSession(session);
            }
            else
            {
                return Ok()
            }
        }
        catch (StripeException e)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
}
}
```

However when trying to implement this I get errors because I think the custom code provided above uses .NET Core and I am using the full .NET framework.

Is there a way around this or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: jeremyo, if possible could you share the errors that you're getting? Without them, we wouldn't be able to accurately provide a solution.

Comment: sorry it is not that i am having errors per say its more of how can i create webhooks with stripe once a user has submitted a successful payment?

Comment: jeremyo, okay, for that I would start by looking at the endpoint you made for creating the checkout session. Presumably, you've got that built already. A webhook endpoint is really similar. I would start by copy-pasting your endpoint code for creating the checkout session. Then, change the endpoint location to something relevant (e.g., stripe-webhooks), and double check that the endpoint can accept POST requests. From there you can test the webhook endpoint locally using this guide here: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/test

Answer (score 0):

This may help someone so I'm posting even although it's a bit late to the table as I couldn't find a relevant answer anywhere.

I had this same issue on a dotNet Core MVC web application (so not an exact answer for the question which is .Net Framework) where the Stripe Webhook was constantly giving a 400 Bad Request response. I just couldn't hit it no matter what I tried.

Eventually, and probably obviously the solution for me was to add the `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` attribute to the `Index()` method as you have in your question above. As .dotNet Core enables the Validation Token on forms I had to explicitly ignore it. The Webhooks worked as soon as I did that.

So the solution for me was:

```
[HttpPost]
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
```

This apparently applies to dot Net Core versions: [see Microsofts Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.ignoreantiforgerytokenattribute)

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

That's works in my Asp.net Framework 4.7, try below code for the webhook

```
    [HttpPost]
   [Route("api/[controller]/webhook")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ProcessRequest()
    {

        var json = await new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadToEndAsync();
        try
        {
            var stripeEvent = EventUtility.ParseEvent(json);

            // Handle the event
            if (stripeEvent.Type == Events.PaymentIntentSucceeded)
            {
                var paymentIntent = stripeEvent.Data.Object as PaymentIntent;
                // Then define and call a method to handle the successful payment intent.
                // handlePaymentIntentSucceeded(paymentIntent);
            }
            else if (stripeEvent.Type == Events.PaymentMethodAttached)
            {
                var paymentMethod = stripeEvent.Data.Object as PaymentMethod;
                // Then define and call a method to handle the successful attachment of a PaymentMethod.
                // handlePaymentMethodAttached(paymentMethod);
            }
            // ... handle other event types
            else
            {
                // Unexpected event type
                Console.WriteLine("Unhandled event type: {0}", stripeEvent.Type);
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (StripeException e)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        //Modification and Saving Data
   
      }
```

After adding this webhook , you can test on locally from https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/test this link